# Adding tabs to my sencha touch app

Tags: tabs, sencha-touch

I have written following app.js class to get 3 tabs in my app using sencha touch. Code of app.js as follows:

```
new Ext.Application({  
             launch: function() {  

          new Ext.TabPanel({  
                sortable: true, // Tap and hold to sort  
                items: [{  
                title: 'Tab 1',  
                html: 'The tabs above are also sortable.(tap and hold)',  
                cls: 'card card5'  
            },  
            {
                title: 'Tab 2',  
                html: 'Tab 2',  
                cls: 'card card4'  
            },    
            {
                title: 'Tab 3',  
                html: 'Tab 3',  
                cls: 'card card3'  
            }]  
      });  
 }  
});
```

Do I have to create card card1 etc? in css or index.html?

Comment: cls have to be specified in your css file. I think you need a iconCls  instead of cls parameter. There are some inbuilt iconCls specified in the sencha css file. for eg iconCls:'home' will provide homebutton image icon to your tab

Comment: Your example is just a cut and paste from the kitchen sink source app! Go to www.sencha.com/learn to learn how to write an app!

Comment: thank you for the link. I was just in a hurry so went through it and put it !

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You don't need to create nothing. These are just a config options.

The Sencha code will generate HTML for ya, with the classnames that apear in your code. You don't have to do nothing, that's the magic.

Sencha is a framework that populate HTML for ya. You define objects, and Sencha, in his turn, will generate HTML with all the properties that you will define in your JS files: Height, Width, Class, ID, Etc.

It doesn't generate CSS for ya. This part you will have to provide by yourself.

Hope that clear things a little more.

Shlomi.